# information_schema views returning multiple rows per column

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a query which will give me certain key information about a given database's columns, but thus far my query seems to return some strange results! I need to know things about column sizes, nullability, uniqueness etc.

So why do I get multiple results per column?

```
SELECT
C.COLUMN_NAME AS COLUMN_NAME,
C.TABLE_NAME AS TABLE_NAME,
C.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
C.COLUMN_DEFAULT AS COLUMN_DEFAULT,
C.DATA_TYPE AS DATA_TYPE,
C.IS_NULLABLE AS IS_NULLABLE,
CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
AND CONSTRAINT_NAME = CC.CONSTRAINT_NAME) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IS_PRIMARY_KEY,
CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'UNIQUE'
AND CONSTRAINT_NAME = CC.CONSTRAINT_NAME) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IS_UNIQUE,
C.NUMERIC_PRECISION AS NUMERIC_PRECISION,
C.NUMERIC_SCALE AS NUMERIC_SCALE,
FK.TABLE_NAME AS FOREIGN_KEY_TABLE_NAME,
FK.COLUMN_NAME AS FOREIGN_KEY_COLUMN_NAME

FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE CC
ON C.COLUMN_NAME = CC.COLUMN_NAME
AND C.TABLE_NAME = CC.TABLE_NAME
LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS TC
ON CC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME

LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS RC
ON TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE FC
ON RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = FC.CONSTRAINT_NAME

LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE FK
ON FC.COLUMN_NAME = FK.COLUMN_NAME
AND FC.TABLE_NAME = FK.TABLE_NAME
WHERE COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(C.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + C.TABLE_NAME), C.COLUMN_NAME, 'IsComputed') = 0
AND TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, you're correct, deleted

Comment: @Yaroslav No prob. The coding style does look reminiscent of MS/Sybase/Oracle, I must say. :)

Comment: To be honest I normally only capitalise my keywords. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have more than one constraint per column, hence if you join with the views containing constraint info, you get multiple rows, one for each constraint on the column.

Another reason could be that the same column and table name appears in different schemas.

You can check for the duplicates with the following query, which just shows you the columns appearing more than once:

```
WITH a as(
    SELECT
    C.COLUMN_NAME AS COLUMN_NAME,
    C.TABLE_NAME AS TABLE_NAME,
    C.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
    C.COLUMN_DEFAULT AS COLUMN_DEFAULT,
    C.DATA_TYPE AS DATA_TYPE,
    C.IS_NULLABLE AS IS_NULLABLE,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE     CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
    AND CONSTRAINT_NAME = CC.CONSTRAINT_NAME) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IS_PRIMARY_KEY,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE     CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'UNIQUE'
    AND CONSTRAINT_NAME = CC.CONSTRAINT_NAME) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IS_UNIQUE,
    C.NUMERIC_PRECISION AS NUMERIC_PRECISION,
    C.NUMERIC_SCALE AS NUMERIC_SCALE,
    FK.TABLE_NAME AS FOREIGN_KEY_TABLE_NAME,
    FK.COLUMN_NAME AS FOREIGN_KEY_COLUMN_NAME

    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
    LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE CC
    ON C.COLUMN_NAME = CC.COLUMN_NAME
    AND C.TABLE_NAME = CC.TABLE_NAME
    LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS TC
    ON CC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME

    LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS RC
    ON TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE FC
    ON RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = FC.CONSTRAINT_NAME

    LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE FK
    ON FC.COLUMN_NAME = FK.COLUMN_NAME
    AND FC.TABLE_NAME = FK.TABLE_NAME
    WHERE COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(C.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + C.TABLE_NAME), C.COLUMN_NAME,     'IsComputed') = 0
    AND TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'
), b as (
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME
      FROM a
    GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME
    HAVING count(*) > 1
)
SELECT a.*
  FROM a JOIN b ON a.COLUMN_NAME = b.COLUMN_NAME AND a.TABLE_NAME = b.TABLE_NAME
```

The CTE `a` is exactly your query from above.

Comment: Ah, but I would assume the `AND TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'` would limit the constraints returned. a column can't have two foreign keys on it at the same time, or at least not in my database!

Comment: A column might be the target of more than one foreign key, though, and have information listed that way round?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you add a `JOIN` to a query, there is the possibility that that relationship will be one-to-many, and thus multiply out the results. You have 5 `JOIN`s here, so presumably one of them has fallen into this case.

My guess would be that multiple constraints can apply to a single column, and you're not filtering out enough possibilities to make that not the case.

The key will be to look at the results you're getting, and see what is actually different in the "duplicate" rows. I sometimes use a query like `SELECT C.*, '--' as [--], CC.*, '--' as [--], ...` to show all the columns of all the joined tables. (The `as [--]` would be `as "--"` in Postgres, `--` in MySQL.)

Comment: Aside: Anyone know how to output a literal \` in the middle of a `code span` in SO's formatting syntax?